# Nvidia card performing.. strangely

Tags: nvidia, graphics, hybrid-graphics, optimus

I own a Nvidia Optimus laptop, with a Nvidia 740M and an Intel HD 4600.

I have installed Gentoo Linux, and I am using native support according to those two wiki pages.
https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/NVIDIA_Driver_with_Optimus_Laptops
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA_Optimus

The issue here is that I am suffering *very* bad performance. First of all, glxgears gives me 300-400 FPS, now before you go screaming at me "GLX IS NOT A REAL BENCHMARK." I'd just like to tell you I used to get 300-400 FPS in Minecraft inside an empty world, and Minecraft is considerably much more graphically intensive than Glxgears... I have seen some people with cards significantly weaker compared in comparison to mine get in the 20000s with Glxgears..

Another "benchmark" I did was running Star Conflict at maximum settings, under Windows, that game with the exact same setting fared fine and gave me a constant 60 FPS (V-Sync), however, under Linux the game lags so bad, I can't even play, it is barely playable on high, and starts being a bit more playable on low.

I am using the latest Nvidia driver in Portage's stable tree. My kernel is 3.18.

Help?